# Package not found tdbc::mysql... How to install?

Tags: package, tcl, tdbc

```
package require tdbc::mysql

set ns [new Simulator]

tdbc::mysql::connection connect db1 -user root -passwd password -db database_name
```

When i compile my above code , it gives error:

```
can't find package tdbc::mysql while executing "package require tdbc::mysql"
```

I installed tcl8.6-tdbc-mysql but it did not work. What can be done ?  I am using Ubuntnu 15.04 and Tcl8.6.

Comment: Please see the posting guidelines for Stack Overflow and include some code that you've tried and errors/issues you're having. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this code only and it gave error. package not found while executing..

Comment: Try and add more details to your question and format your code if you can

Comment: What OS? What Tcl distribution?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you have to install the `tdbc` package (which is the main, governing package), `tdbcmysql` package (which is specific to MySQL) and also have `libmysql` installed on the system and available in library path.

Comment: There are many libmysql packages like libmysql-cil-dev,  libmysqld-dev, libmysql-java, libmysqlclient18, libmysql++-dev, libmysql-ocaml etc.. Which one to install and can you elaborate "available in library path".

Comment: I am currently a Windows user and have used Linux occasionally, so I may error, but in general, in case you just want to use a package, you do not need the ```-dev``` variant of it; ```-java```, ```-ocaml``` are specific to these respective languages, so you do not need them either. You need the one which will install ```libmysql.18.so``` or similar. So, do install ```tdbc``` and ```tdbcmysql``` Tcl packages and then interactively try to ```package require tdbc::mysql``` in a Tcl session. It will complain which specific library it is missing.

Comment: By "available in library path" I mean that any program on the system can find this library, either because it is installed on the path that is standard for library placement on your system or because the path it is installed in is specified in the ```LD_LIBRARY_PATH``` environment variable. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: Looks like ```libmysqlclient18``` may be the right choice.